# React - this is undefined inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ran into problem, when i pass value from child to parent class it works but when i want to push it from parent to 'grandparent' it tells me that 'this' is undefined and i can't pass function as 'function={this.functionName}'

Here is component that is making me problems:

```
class MessageList extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        applyFor: ''
    }
    this.updateApply = this.updateApply.bind(this);
}

updateApply = (posName) => {
    this.setState({
        applyFor: posName
    })
}...
```

and this is my render function

```
render() {
    return(
    this.props.messages.map(function(message, index){
        if(message.type === 'out') { 
            if(message.qType === 'quick reply'){
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <BotTextMessage key={index} message={message.message.text} />
                        <FadeIn>
                            <QuickReplyWrapper key={index} options={message.message.options} />
                        </FadeIn>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ); 
            } else {
                return <BotTextMessage key={index} message={message.message.text} />;
            }
        } else {
        // console.log(this)
        return  <OpenPositionWrapper updateApply={this.updateApply}/>

        }
    }));

}
```

when i log this it is undefined and for 'updateApply' it gives me:

> MessageList.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateApply' of undefined

Comment: We need to see more of your `render` function. That would be fine as shown. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Note that when you use the property initializer form with an arrow function (your `updateApply = ...` code), `this.updateApply = this.updateApply.bind(this);` is unnecessary and pointless. You used an arrow function, which will inherit `this` (which is what you want). (My guess is you added the `bind` when it didn't work without it, but I thought I'd let you know...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
render() {
    return(
    this.props.messages.map((message, index) => {
        if(message.type === 'out') { 
            if(message.qType === 'quick reply'){
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <BotTextMessage key={index} message={message.message.text} />
                        <FadeIn>
                            <QuickReplyWrapper key={index} options={message.message.options} />
                        </FadeIn>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ); 
            } else {
                return <BotTextMessage key={index} message={message.message.text} />;
            }
        } else {
        // console.log(this)
        return  <OpenPositionWrapper updateApply={this.updateApply}/>

        }
    }));

}
```